# Is it ok & common to say "I feel exhausted because of my exhausting daughter"?

Tags: word-usage

Ok,

> to exhaust: to make somebody feel very tired [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exhaust_2#exhaust_2__4)

the word "**exhausted**" is quite popular. For example, "*I feel exhausted*".

However, I rarely see ""**exhausting**"".

Can I say like this "*I feel exhausted because of my exhausting daughter*"?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence sounds awkward to me. That is because the adjective 'exhausted/ting' means making *you* feel tired. Now, if your daughter is *exhausting*, it means that she makes **you feel tired because of her whatsoever quality** (say, for example, talkativeness).

[OALD says](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exhausting?q=exhausting) -

> *I find **her exhausting** --she never stops talking*.

There's no need to specify that *you become exhausted* when the scenario is clear that it is because of your daughter's some quality, it is exhausting. In other words, it seems *redundant*.

---

It is something like saying, "I feel **bored** because of this **boring work.**" Here, boredom is attributed to that work and if you do it, it's obvious that you feel bored!

Comment: But we can of course say, *"This is boring work, but I don't get bored easily."*

Comment: But there you **don't** get bored, so it *has* to be specified! :) @DamkerngT.